# Shell script 'read' doesnt work with 'EOF'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

This script below is working, I want to read a value from files svc1.data and used it in syntax.

```
administrator@dev-91:~$ while read -r name port ignored; do echo $name $port ; done <svc1.data
bendita-nussa 4003
```

But this script below doesn't work, it keeps saying : ***-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'***

```
administrator@dev-91:~$ while read -r name port ignored; do
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: $name
  namespace: nussa
spec:
  hosts:
    - $name.nussa.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: $name
            port:
              number: $port
            subset: v1
; done <svc1.data
```

Please help, whats wrong with the 2nd script..

Comment: You didn't close your HEREDOC https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04

Comment: This question looks like it's just a typographic error. `<<EOF` _always_ requires a paired `EOF` at the end; that's not different here from any other heredoc use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : You are right of course, but shouldn't the error then be _done missing_ or _unexpected end-of-file_, instead of _unexpected semicolon_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close the HEREDOC, like this:

```sh
while read -r name port ignored; do
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: $name
  namespace: nussa
spec:
  hosts:
    - $name.nussa.svc.cluster.local
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: $name
            port:
              number: $port
            subset: v1
EOF
done <svc1.data
```